# Convert the strings to 12 hours format

Tags: python, python-2.7

I need some help with my snippet. I have got the strings that range from 0 to 24.

If I have the string that show `13`, I would like to convert it to 12 hours time to make the string show `1` instead of `13`.

```
for program_end_time in self.program_end_time:
    program_stop_hours = str(program_end_time.hour)

    #Now I would like to convert it to 12 hours instead of 24
```

The reason I want to convert from 24 hours to 12 hours is because I want to reduce the code instead of this:

```
 if program_stop_hours == "0":
     program_stop_hours = "12"
     program_AM_PM = 'AM'
 elif program_stop_hours == "1":
     program_stop_hours = "1"
     program_AM_PM = 'AM'
 elif program_stop_hours == "2":
     program_stop_hours = "2"
     program_AM_PM = 'AM'
 elif program_stop_hours == "3":
     program_stop_hours = "3"
     program_AM_PM = 'AM'
 elif program_stop_hours == "4":
     program_stop_hours = "4"
     program_AM_PM = 'AM'
 elif program_stop_hours == "5":
     program_stop_hours = "5"
     program_AM_PM = 'AM'
 elif program_stop_hours == "6":
     program_stop_hours = "6"
     program_AM_PM = 'AM'
 elif program_stop_hours == "7":
     program_stop_hours = "7"
     program_AM_PM = 'AM'
 elif program_stop_hours == "8":
     program_stop_hours = "8"
     program_AM_PM = 'AM'
 elif program_stop_hours == "9":
     program_stop_hours = "9"
     program_AM_PM = 'AM'
 elif program_stop_hours == "10":
     program_stop_hours = "10"
     program_AM_PM = 'AM'
 elif program_stop_hours == "11":
     program_stop_hours = "11"
     program_AM_PM = 'AM'
 elif program_stop_hours == "12":
     program_stop_hours = "12"
     program_AM_PM = 'PM'
 elif program_stop_hours == "13":
     program_stop_hours = "1"
     program_AM_PM = 'PM'
 elif program_stop_hours == "14":
     program_stop_hours = "2"
     program_AM_PM = 'PM'
 elif program_stop_hours == "15":
     program_stop_hours = "3"
     program_AM_PM = 'PM'
 elif program_stop_hours == "16":
     program_stop_hours = "4"
     program_AM_PM = 'PM'
 elif program_stop_hours == "17":
     program_stop_hours = "5"
     program_AM_PM = 'PM'
 elif program_stop_hours == "18":
     program_stop_hours = "6"
     program_AM_PM = 'PM'
 elif program_stop_hours == "19":
     program_stop_hours = "7"
     program_AM_PM = 'PM'
 elif program_stop_hours == "20":
     program_stop_hours = "8"
     program_AM_PM = 'PM'
 elif program_stop_hours == "21":
     program_stop_hours = "9"
     program_AM_PM = 'PM'
 elif program_stop_hours == "22":
     program_stop_hours = "10"
     program_AM_PM = 'PM'
 elif program_stop_hours == "23":
     program_stop_hours = "11"
     program_AM_PM = 'PM'
```

I want to make it something to show like this:

```
if program_stop_hours >= 0 and if program_stop_hours <= 12:
   program_stop_hours = str(program_stop_hours, convert_to_12_hours)
   program_AM_PM = 'AM'
else:
   program_stop_hours = str(program_stop_hours, convert_to_12_hours)
   program_AM_PM = 'PM'
```

Can you please show me an example how I could do that in python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You really just need to test two cases: program_stop_hours is less or equal 12 or it is more than 12. You can do it like this:

```
program_stop_hours = input("Enter program stop hours: ")
if program_stop_hours >= 0 and program_stop_hours <= 12:
    program_stop_hours = str(program_stop_hours)
    program_AM_PM = 'AM'
else:
    program_stop_hours = str(program_stop_hours - 12)
    program_AM_PM = 'PM'

print program_stop_hours
print program_AM_PM
```

Be sure to properly handle the various conditions like program_stop_hours is: less than zero; exactly 12 (make sure it does what you intend in that case); more than 24 (you don't test for that); and exactly 24 (to make sure it handles that case as you intend).

Comment: Thank you very much, this is the answer what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

that will do, you will have to mod it a bit to fit your formattig need, but it's short

```
>>> def convert24(x):
    am = "AM" if x < 12 else "PM"
    r = 12 if not x%12 else x%12
    return "{:0>2d}:00 {}".format(r, am)

>>> convert24(0)
'12:00 AM'
>>> convert24(13)
'01:00 PM'
>>> convert24(23)
'11:00 PM'
```